# Using Java streams grouping the list data based on the date intervals and sum the amount field

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider there is a class : **Partner**

```
Class Partner {
 LocalDate invoiceDate;  
 BigDecimal amount;  
}
```

Now, I have a list of Partner objects sorted in descending order eg:

```
[Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-21, amount=400), 
 Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-20, amount=400), 
 Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-11, amount=400), 
 Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-10, amount=400),
 .....,
 .....]
```

In the above sample data the field "invoiceDate" is for January month.
***note:** the list will have data for 12 months or above.*

Now,

1. I want to group the data in 15 days interval .i.e.
   *First interval,* 1st day to 15th day of the month [1 - 15].
   *Second interval,* 16th day to Last day of the month [16 - 30/31/28/29].
2. And finally sum the amount value between the date range.

**Calculation form the above sample data :**
*first interval [1-15] :* 2 rows qualifies => [invoiceDate=2020-01-11 and invoiceDate=2020-01-10]
*second interval [16-31] :* 2 rows qualifies => [invoiceDate=2020-01-21 and invoiceDate=2020-01-20]

**The final output data should look like this :**

```
[Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-31, amount=800), 
Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-15, amount=800)]
```

*note : In the final output invoiceDate should be the last day of the interval.*

Comment: This would be an interesting question... if it included your attempt so far.

Comment: There is no reason to use streams for that.

Comment: @ernest_k I am able to write a stream to group the data based on date and sum the amount, but adding the interval logic is where I am seeking some advice.

Comment: @farzainpathan that's all that's needed. Just add what you've done and indicate where you're stuck, and people are glad to help :-)

Comment: And, you've tried A B C, they didn't work because...

Comment: `partnerList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Partner::getInvoiceDate))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(localDateListEntry -> {
     LocalDate date = localDateListEntry.getKey();
     BigDecimal sum = localDateListEntry.getValue()
       .stream()
       .map(Partner::getAmout)
       .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
     
     return new Partner(date, sum);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Is the list sorted? The one in your example is sorted by descending date.

Comment: @ernest_k With the above code, I was able to achieve the grouping of the data with date. like said I seeking advice for grouping the date in intervals. (apologies for the format still learning)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yes the list will be sorted in descending order

Comment: @farzainpathan Add your tried code in post then it will be more readable

Comment: @farzainpathan [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63262101/edit) with that code you've tried instead of sharing it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupingBy` would help in such a situation. Here is one of the approaches:

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
Map<String, BigDecimal> dateRangeToSumMap = list
                    .stream()
                    .collect(
                            groupingBy(e -> e.invoiceDate.getDayOfMonth() > 15 ? "16-31" : "1-16",
                                       mapping(
                                               Partner::getAmount, 
                                               reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
                                               )
                                       )
                            );

// iterate the map to get the output
dateRangeToSumMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
                
                System.out.println("Date Range = " + k + " , Sum = " + v);
                
            });
```

**Output**:

```java
Date Range = 1-16 , Sum = 800
Date Range = 16-31 , Sum = 800
```

> The final output data should look like this :

```java
[Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-31, amount=800), 
Partner(invoiceDate=2020-01-15, amount=800)]
```

This can be constructed with the map we have.

> note : In the final output invoiceDate should be the last day of the interval.

With `year` and `month`, we can get the correct last day of the interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you at least something to start with:

```
Function<Partner, LocalDate> getInterval = (partner) -> {
  // compute if day is before 15th of month and return either 15th
  // of month or last day of month
  return null; 
};

Collection<Partner> partners = Arrays.asList();
Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> result = partners.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(getInterval, Partner::getAmount, (a1, a2) -> a1.add(a2)));
```

You can use the map collector with the merge function to get the sum for all elements with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

You can first map `invoiceDate` into 15-day interval date. Then use `Collectors.toMap` to map the data into for `invoiceDate` and sum the `amount` in merge function by creating new `Parter` object. Finally get the map values as list.

```
Map<LocalDate, Partner> result = list.stream()
    .map(p -> new Partner(p.getInvoiceDate().getDayOfMonth() > 15
        ? p.getInvoiceDate().withDayOfMonth(p.getInvoiceDate().lengthOfMonth())
        : p.getInvoiceDate().withDayOfMonth(15),
          p.getAmount()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Partner::getInvoiceDate, e -> e,
        (a, b) -> new Partner(a.getInvoiceDate(), a.getAmount().add(b.getAmount()))));

List<Partner> res = new ArrayList<>(result.values());
```

**Another approach :**

You can simplified the code without creating the Partner object the way @Naman suggested

```
static LocalDate getIntervalDate(LocalDate d) {
    return (d.getDayOfMonth() > 15 ? d.withDayOfMonth(d.lengthOfMonth()) 
                                   : d.withDayOfMonth(15));
}

List<Partner> res = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> getIntervalDate(e.getInvoiceDate()), 
                              e -> e.getAmount(), (a, b) -> a.add(b)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new Partner(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you can improve on reducing the creation of new `Partner` instances, if you move the logic of `map` for the date part to a method and then invoke it as a `keyMapper` for `toMap`..further for this use case, collect with a `valueMapper` to include the amount as value and simplifying the merge operation..then streaming the entries of the `Map` obtained to finally `map` to the desired object as an output.

Answer (score 0):

Java's verbosity and lack of a tuple type makes the code somewhat longer, this can be done in one pass without any grouping.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Partner> partners = Arrays.asList(
                new Partner(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 21), BigDecimal.valueOf(400)),
                new Partner(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 20), BigDecimal.valueOf(400)),
                new Partner(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 11), BigDecimal.valueOf(400)),
                new Partner(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 10), BigDecimal.valueOf(400))
        );

        Accumulator results = IntStream
                .range(0, partners.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(i, partners.get(i)))
                .reduce(new Accumulator(), (Accumulator acc, Map.Entry<Integer, Partner> e) -> {
                    Partner p = e.getValue();
                    if (p.invoiceDate.getMonthValue() == acc.month || e.getKey() == 0) {
                        BiWeeklyReport bucket = p.invoiceDate.getDayOfMonth() <= 15 ? acc.first : acc.second;
                        bucket.amount = bucket.amount.add(p.amount);
                        bucket.invoiceDate = bucket.invoiceDate.isAfter(p.invoiceDate) ? bucket.invoiceDate : p.invoiceDate;
                        acc.month = bucket.invoiceDate.getMonthValue();
                    }
                    if (e.getKey() == partners.size() - 1 || p.invoiceDate.getMonthValue() != acc.month) {
                        if (acc.first.amount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                            acc.reports.add(acc.first);
                        }
                        if (acc.second.amount.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) {
                            acc.reports.add(acc.second);
                        }
                        acc.first = new BiWeeklyReport();
                        acc.second = new BiWeeklyReport();
                    }
                    return acc;
                }, (acc1, acc2) -> {
                    acc1.reports.addAll(acc2.reports);
                    return acc1;
                });
        System.out.println(results.reports);
    }

    private static class Partner {
        LocalDate invoiceDate;
        BigDecimal amount;

        private Partner(LocalDate invoiceDate, BigDecimal amount) {
            this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }

    private static class BiWeeklyReport {
        BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        LocalDate invoiceDate = LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1);

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BiWeeklyReport{" +
                    "amount=" + amount.longValue() +
                    ", invoiceDate=" + DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(invoiceDate) +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    private static class Accumulator {
        List<BiWeeklyReport> reports = new ArrayList<>();
        BiWeeklyReport first = new BiWeeklyReport();
        BiWeeklyReport second = new BiWeeklyReport();
        int month = -1;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[BiWeeklyReport{amount=800, invoiceDate=2020-01-11}, BiWeeklyReport{amount=800, invoiceDate=2020-01-21}]
```